# minlength in a template don't return error angular

Tags: angular

I have the following form :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-z1l7sn?file=app/app.component.html

But my html template minlength is never applied to the FormControl.

This never throws error.

How can I fix it ?

```
 <input matInput type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="input" formControlName="newPassword" required
        minlength="useMinLength ? selectedMinLength : 0"
        pattern="^[/\S/]+$">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed like this 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-ncycwu

```
  <input matInput type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="input" formControlName="newPassword" required
          minlength="{{useMinLength ? selectedMinLength : 0}}"
          pattern="^[/\S/]+$">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the [mininum length](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minlength) validator on your Reactive Form Controls! For instance,

```
selectedMinLength = 6
.
.
ngOnInit(){
  this.passwordForm = new FormGroup({
    newPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.selectedMinLength)])
 })
}
```

Comment: but the pattern and required do work from template, why not minlength ?

Comment: I think this is because the error is triggered by reactive form's `valid` or `error`, that is why you need to explicitly specify the minLength validator on your reactive form controls

Comment: But the code I provided should work. I have already tested in on the stackblitz you provided

Comment: Oh, right! Yes! I just realised its that ternary operator thats causing it. Sorry I didn't check your .html file just now